# Is it possible to update xid/url references for my page's comments?

Tags: facebook, widget, comments

Our FB Comment widget was implemented incorrectly. The "url" parameter has a stray single quote before "http", like so:

```
<fb:comments numposts="10" publish_feed="true" migrated="1" class="fb_iframe_widget" url="'http://www.mysite.com/2596795">
```

Long story short, we didn't catch this till six months down the line. Now Facebook comments are being keyed on our site on the xid/url (I putzed around with the Graph API):

```
http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments_v1.php?app_id=XXXXXXXXXX&xid=http\u0025253A\u0025252F\u0025252Fwww.mysite.com\u00252Fdetail\u00252F2596795
```

Note how FB defaulted the URL to be the URL of the comment itself, with the (malformed) URL as the xid/url params.

Now that I would like to fix the facebook comments widget, how would I go about updating each facebook ID to match to the correct page?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can do anything with the migrated version to set it to the right URL.

But just I wrote a complete tutorial of how to leave the migrated boxes as they are,

but start using the new 'href' version in the new comments-boxes,

so if you think it can help you then visit the [**tutorial**](http://www.facebook.com/gil.goldshlager.dev?v=app_190322544333196)